# Validate entity without saving it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have entity

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Column(name = "field", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String field;
}
```

how I can validate that `field` is no longer then 10 chars without saving it?

Comment: may be in your setter by checking `field.length()` .

Comment: I have many such fields and I don't want to write checks in every setter. I want generic solution which will not require unnecessary coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created small utility class to solve exactly this problem.

```
public class HibernateValidator {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Class, List<FieldConstraint>> constraints = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public List<ValidationViolation> validate(Object entity) {
        List<FieldConstraint> constraints = getFieldConstraints(entity);

        return constraints.stream()
                .flatMap(x -> validate(entity, x))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Stream<ValidationViolation> validate(Object entity, FieldConstraint x) {
        String value;
        try {
            x.getField().setAccessible(true);
            value = (String) x.getField().get(entity);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't get value", e);
        }
        if (value != null && value.length() > x.getSize()) {
            return Stream.of(ValidationViolation.builder()
                    .fieldName(x.getField().getName())
                    .build());
        } else {
            return Stream.empty();
        }
    }

    private List<FieldConstraint> getFieldConstraints(Object entity) {
        return constraints.computeIfAbsent(entity.getClass(),
                clazz -> Stream.of(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
                        .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(String.class))
                        .flatMap(x -> {
                            Column annotation = x.getAnnotation(Column.class);
                            if (annotation == null) {
                                return Stream.empty();
                            } else {
                                return Stream.of(FieldConstraint.builder()
                                        .field(x)
                                        .size(annotation.length())
                                        .build());
                            }
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    public static class ValidationViolation {
        private final String fieldName;
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    private static class FieldConstraint {
        private final Field field;
        private final int size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Only for my understanding, there are already libs solving this problem. Maybe your solution works to but i.e. the Hibernate Beanvalidator is build for this purpose https://hibernate.org/validator/

Comment: I didn't found any lib able to process `@Column` attribute. See all other answers.

Comment: That's correct but the `@Column` annotation is used by JPA for generating the DB structure and abused by your solution. The Single Responsebility Principle is violated by your solution. Is it just a quick and dirty or a long time solution? In a few month nobody except you will understand why the entity is validated.

Comment: All other solution require two annotations containing same information. I don't think it is better.

Comment: Sorry mate you don't understand my point. You're correct with your point that you need two annotations but there are a few clean code and design principles which are useful to structure code and make it maintainable for other devs.

Comment: I don't see how I violate SRP here. If there is violation it is in `@Column` not in my code.

Comment: The violation is not in `@Column`. It's possible to use JPA and Bean Validation separately. The JPA annotations deal with the _database schema_ and have no validation functionality outside the database returning an error on malformed input. If you don't have the JPA provider generate the schema for you I'm not even sure the `length` attribute matters. The Bean Validation API deals with _validating beans_ and provides ways to supply custom messages, different validation based on groups, etc. For instance, maybe your field is a password field and admins must have a password of length > 8 (cont.)

Comment: ...but regular users only need a password of length > 6. You can specify this behavior using the Bean Validation annotations but not with the JPA annotations. Yes, in your specific case you may need to "duplicate" information but that's just the consequence of the two APIs having different purposes. Note that the JPA specification includes the ability to use Bean Validation for validation. Also note that Bean Validation provides a decent number of useful annotations, such as `@Size` having a `min` option, `@Past` that requires dates to represent the past, or `@Pattern` for regex matching.

Answer (score 8):

Use [bean validation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "field", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String field;
}
```

Or the hibernate-specific annotaion `@Length(max = 10)` may be used too.

Then, you can validate entity with [validator](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#validationapi) object:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyEntity>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(myEntity));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not duplicate information in `@Length`? `@Column` already have it.

Comment: I don't know the way to do it. The '@Length' annotation is for validation, but the '@Column' is for ORM (database structure). They works on different layers.

Comment: The length you specify in `@Column` will only be used for DDL, so using that alone won't work for validation

Comment: Small correction. The '@Length' annotation is hibernate-specific, and the '@Size' is from bean validation specification. There is no information about JPA realization in question, so i've changed annotation in answer to '@Size'

Answer (score 0):

`@Column` has an attribute `length` that you can use to set the length of the column, this will result in SQL Exception when a value with greater length is inserted. And you can use `@Size(max=SOME_VALUE)` for bean validation.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Size(max=10)
    @Column(name = "field", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String field;
}
```